# Sqoop Incremental Import Error using Date Column

Tags: hive, sqoop

I'm trying to incrementally import using sqoop . It is working for the column id but when I'm trying to do the same thing in date column it is showing an error , the date column in mysql is in varchar format .

code :

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://$hostName/$dbName --username $userName --password $pass --query "select * , 'username' as user_name, 'date' as created_date from $tableName WHERE $cloumnName between ${values[0]} and ${values[1]} AND \$CONDITIONS"  --target-dir outputPath --append --m mapperNo --split-by splitByValue --check-column cloumnName --incremental $imode
```

Error :

> 16/12/20 01:18:46 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Character column (date_field) can not be used to determine which rows to incrementally import.

Comment: The error message is explicit: Sqoop requires a "numeric" data type with monotic increment, such as an Int or a Date. Your DB uses a String, you are screwed. Anyway, do you have a question??

Comment: Thank You for the answer , we can not do an incremental import with string right ?

Comment: Sure you can. You can write your own code that will calculate last loaded date (select max for example) and then pass it as a parameter into sqoop query. it will work with strings. This method is very flexible.

Comment: You can also define a "generated column" in your MySQL table to `cast(STRING_DATE as date)` and use that Date column for Sqoop. Or create a view. Be creative!